# Как из окна открытого проекта в PyCharm перейти в окно выбора проект (стартовое окно)

Tags: pycharm

Проблема следующая - присутствует множество несвязанных проектов, которые надо отлаживать в процессе деятельности. При старте IDE открывается удобное окно выбора проекта, в которое бы хотелось переходить после окончания работы с предыдущим. Прикреплять 1 проект к другому не хочется, тк не люблю много вкладок, а переоткрывать IDE каждый раз - лень. Есть способ перехода менее костыльный?

Answer (score 2):

При закрытии проекта на close project это окно выбора проекта будет появляться, так что перезапуск не нужен.

А как открыть несколько проектов одновременно можно почитать в официальной документации:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/opening-multiple-projects.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]